# Shifting MAC in bond

Tags: networking, mac, network-bonding

I have a system running 18.04 which requires a bond due to bandwidth. However what i have found is that the MAC address may change upon boot up. The software i am using requires a MAC which is fixed otherwise it will lock down.

Is there anyway to modify the netplan info for this. Apologies if this has already been posted but i have looked around already.

Comment: Can the MAC of the bond change depending on which NIC starts up first? Found this which would explain my problem. https://blog.widodh.nl/2015/09/ubuntu-and-the-changing-mac-address-with-bonding/

Comment: actually do i simply have to assign the primary in netplan under parameters. This is something i didnt do.